# Suddenly Kafka Streams (scala) app falls into the rejoining process (with no obvious reason) and never completes it

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am messing aroung with Kafka Streams handled by the K8s.
It goes more or less fine so far, yet weird behaviour is observed on the test environment:

> [Consumer clientId=dbe-livestream-kafka-streams-77185a88-71a7-40cd-8774-aeecc04054e1-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=dbe-livestream-kafka-streams] We received an assignment [_livestream.dbe.tradingcore.sporteventmappings-table-0, _livestream.dbe.tradingcore.sporteventmappings-table-2, _livestream.dbe.tradingcore.sporteventmappings-table-4, _livestream.dbe.tradingcore.sporteventmappings-table-6, livestream.dbe.tennis.results-table-0, livestream.dbe.tennis.results-table-2, livestream.dbe.tennis.results-table-4, livestream.dbe.tennis.results-table-6, _livestream.dbe.betmanager.sporteventmappings-table-0, _livestream.dbe.betmanager.sporteventmappings-table-2, _livestream.dbe.betmanager.sporteventmappings-table-4, _livestream.dbe.betmanager.sporteventmappings-table-6] that doesn't match our current subscription Subscribe(_livestream.dbe.betmanager.sporteventmappings-table|_livestream.dbe.trading_states|_livestream.dbe.tradingcore.sporteventmappings-table|livestream.dbe.tennis.markets|livestream.dbe.tennis.markets-table); it is likely that the subscription has changed since we joined the group. Will try re-join the group with current subscription

As far as I understand, internal state somehow got broken, and Stream's source of truth conflicts with the broker/zookeeper's one. This behaviour never terminates: I just let it hang for few days beingh busy with another stuff, and still it's the, reported at the `WARN` level. More than that: no `ERROR`s were reported for this time.

I did not change nothing; did not deploy new instances; did not manipulate Kafka brokers in any way that might affect abovementioned Kafka Streams app. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message itself indicates, that something is wrong with your subscription. This may happen if you have two Kafka Streams instances using the same `application.id`, but both don't subscribe to the exact same topics.

In your case, the subscription does not contain `livestream.dbe.tennis.results-table` but corresponding partitions are assigned.

Note, that Kafka Streams requires that all instances with the same `application.id` are required to execute the exact same `Topology` and thus subscribe to the exact same topics.

Comment: I see the message, but it was just a `WARN`, saying that KS gonna try to rejoin. Should such an error be fixed by the KS generally or I experience an expected behavior?

Comment: Well, KS tries to be resilient against the issue (so trying to rejoin is not unexpected). But I don't see that there is a bug that need to be fixed atm (given the provided data). It seems more like a user error, that different applications use the same `application.id`. There must be some app with the same `application.id` that subscribes to `livestream.dbe.tennis.results-table` -- hence, the correct "fix" is to let each app use its' own `application.id`.

Comment: I am having the same issue in a JUnit test with Embedded Kafka and Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder. There is no "second application" running and I am cleaning up temporary folder for Zookeeper and Kafka before each run. Still if I have num.stream.threads set to anything other than 1 I get that error in 6 runs from 10, sometimes it starts and runs reasonably well (still throwing the same warnings but seemingly not affecting test results).

Comment: Maybe a bug in Spring? (Spring is doing a lot of weird stuff, and does not always use Kafka Streams "correctly"...)